# JavaScript. How to hook aceessing to object

Tags: javascript, navigator

Where a lot of information about hooking functions. But. Is it possible to hook accessing to objects?
For example.
We have "navigator" object. It has a lot of params. We need to hook accessing to UserAgent param. Is it possible? Mybe I may use define of setter/getter? Or something else...

As we know where no way to replace navigator object (it is read only). So we cant slove it simple like:

```
var blabla = navigator;
blabla.UserAgent = "myagent";
```

etc

Regards!

ps
sorry for my english :)

Comment: What do you mean by "hook" ? preventing api access ? do something when acceded ?

Comment: yes. do something, for example replace UserAgent param and call some function.

Comment: Is the access to that variable made by some code you control ?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but if you want to do something when a navigator.userAgent is accessed, you can redefine it as a property.

```
(function() {
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, "userAgent", {
        get: function() {
            console.log("hello from useragent");
            return userAgent;
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Is it possible to execute the same function for accessing *any* property?